# Prove that if f $\in L^1$, then $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}: \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x+t)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The title pretty much says it all: I'm stuck with this problem and I would appreciate any help. I feel like I'm in the middle of nowhere with this one.
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \in L^1$. For any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we define **the transfer of $f$ by $t$** as the function $f_t:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f_t(x)=f(x+t),$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_t$.

The only thing I have in mind is that if I could somehow prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f_t = \int_{t}^{\infty}f$ then in a similar manner I would be able to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{0}f_t = \int_{-\infty}^{t}f$. I can't see the next step though. I was thinking of defining a sequence $(t_n)$ that converges to $t$, so that the dominated convergence theorem would be accesible, but I can't work it out.

**P.S:** I would prefer if someone could give me a good hint for this one rather than a detailed solution; any help is appreciated though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using Dominated Convergence, can I recommend that you work directly from the definition of the integral?

You could first deal with the case where $f$ is positive. Here, the definition of the integral is
$$ \int f(x) dx = \sup_{0 \leq \varphi \leq f, \\ \varphi {\rm \ simple}} \int \varphi(x) dx.$$

But if $\varphi(x)$ is a positive simple function bounded above by $f(x)$, then $\varphi(x + t)$ is a positive simple function bounded above by $f(x + t)$...

Comment: Echoing this sentiment. When in doubt, use simple functions. They make life, well, simple.

Comment: I was in that direction but I strongly rejected it for some reason. Guess my instincts got all messed up this time. Thanks a lot guys. Also @CameronWilliams I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: @Kps By the way, if you really want to, you _can_ argue using dominated convergence. You need to observe that there exists a sequence of simple functions $\varphi_n(x)$ such that $|\varphi_n(x)| \leq f(x)$ and $\varphi_n (x) \to f(x)$ pointwise. (Imagine drawing a "staircase" under the graph of $f(x)$, then make the heights of the steps get smaller and smaller...) Then consider the sequence $\varphi_n(x + t)$...

Comment: Yeah I eventually figured, anyway for some reason my gut keeps saying "approximation" this days. Your way is simpler though :)